# Why is the output of this c program like this?

Tags: c

The ouput of the following code is coming out to be   512 0 2 however it should have been 512 0 0. Can somebody please help !

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        union a
        {
            int i;
            char ch[2];
        };
        union a z = { 512 };
        printf("%d %d %d\n",z.i, z.ch[0], z.ch[1]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Read about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Hint: change `512` to `0x123`  and change `%d %d %d` to `%x %x %x`. This makes it possibly easier to understand.

Comment: 512 0 2 is correct output. What makes you think that it is not correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Depending on endianess and size of integer there are various possible correct results possible. Please explain in detail why you expect 512 0 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume for simplicity that int is 2 bytes.In this case the memory for your struct will be 2 bytes.Let's also assume that the union is located on address 0x0000.By the results you are getting i can tell you're using a little endian machine - address 0x0000 -> value 0x0000, address 0x0002 -> value 0x0002.

`z.i` prints 512 correctly.

`z.ch[0]` getting the value from address 0x0000 which is 0

`z.ch[1]` getting the value from address 0x0002 which is 2

> Big Endian Byte Order: The most significant byte (the "big end") of
>   the data is placed at the byte with the lowest address. The rest of
>   the data is placed in order in the next three bytes in memory.
>
> Little Endian Byte Order: The least significant byte (the "little
>   end") of the data is placed at the byte with the lowest address. The
>   rest of the data is placed in order in the next three bytes in memory.

Answer (score 5):

You have build a union of two bytes. Know you assign 512d (0x0200) to the union.
First Byte = `0x00`
Second Byte = `0x02`

The integer (`int16_t`) `i` and your array `ch[2]` use the same memory!

Comment: Small correction. The size of `a` depends on the size of the int type, so it can be two or more bytes. The idea however is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some confusion with a struct and a union.

A union uses the same memory for all of its members and a struct has a separate memory for each member.

See the following extension of your code (at [IDEone](https://ideone.com/rBxQtq) ):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    union a
    {
        int i;
        char ch[2];
    };
    union a aa = { 512 };
    printf("%d %d %d\n",aa.i, aa.ch[0], aa.ch[1]);

    struct b
    {
        int i;
        char ch[2];
    };
    struct b bb = { 512 };
    printf("%d %d %d\n",bb.i, bb.ch[0], bb.ch[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Union: 512 0 2
Struct: 512 0 0
```